# Need to change the JS events format to fit into Jquery and Meteor (Template.mysite.events) format

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am looking to paste this script into my meteor app, I can't figure out how to change a bit the formatting to make it fit in my "Template.page.events" , can someone help?

I am a beginner and having a hard time with it

```
(function(){
  var v = document.querySelector('video'),
      n = document.querySelector('source').src.replace(/.*\/|\..*$/g,''),
      c = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      save = document.querySelector('#save ul'),
      ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  v.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(ev){

    var ratio = v.videoWidth/v.videoHeight,
        w = 400,
        h = parseInt(w / ratio, 10),
        time = 0,
        img = null,
        li = null;
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h + 40;

    v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(ev){
      if(v.paused){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(v, 0, 40, w, h);
        ctx.font = '20px Calibri';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
        ctx.fillText(n, 5, 20);
        time = format(v.currentTime);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillText(time, 395 - ctx.measureText(time).width, 20);
      }
    },false);
    c.addEventListener('click',function(ev){
      li = document.createElement('li');
      img = document.createElement('img');
      li.appendChild(img);
      save.appendChild(li);
      img.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    },false);
  },false);
  function format(time){
    var hours = parseInt((time / 60 / 60) % 60, 10),
        mins = parseInt((time / 60) % 60, 10),
        secs = parseInt(time, 10) % 60,
        hourss = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(hours, 10) + ':',
        minss = (mins < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(mins, 10) + ':',
        secss  = (secs < 10 ? '0' : '') +(secs % 60),
        timestring = ( hourss !== '00:' ? hourss : '' ) + minss + secss;
    return timestring;
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose we have this Meteor template markup :

```
<template name="page">
  <video controls autoplay>
    <source src="/videos/video.mp4">
  </video>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <ul>
    {{#each screenshots}}
      {{> screenshot}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="screenshot">
  <li>
    <img src="{{source}}">
  </li>
</template>
```

I've added a subtemplate to handle the screenshot list generation done the Meteor way : without manipulating the DOM directly to insert HTML elements.

First we need to create a `reactive-var` to hold the screenshot list sources as an array :

```
Template.page.onCreated(function(){
  this.screenshots = new ReactiveVar([]);
});

Template.page.helpers({
  screenshots:function(){
    return Template.instance().screenshots.get();
  }
});
```

Don't forget to `meteor add reactive-var`.

We can save as template properties references to `video` and `canvas` elements inside the `onRendered` template lifecycle event :

```
Template.page.onRendered(function(){
  this.video = this.find("video");
  this.canvas = this.find("canvas");
});
```

Then we have to rewrite the standard HTML event handling using Meteor event maps which is pretty straightforward, just use the syntax `"event selector"`.

```
Template.page.events({
  "loadedmetadata video":function(event,template){
    var ratio = template.video.videoWidth / template.video.videoHeight;
    var canvasWidth = 400;
    var canvasHeight = parseInt(canvasWidth / ratio, 10);
    template.canvas.width = w;
    template.canvas.height = h + 40;
  },
  "timeupdate video":function(event,template){
    function format(time){
      var hours = parseInt((time / 60 / 60) % 60, 10);
      var mins = parseInt((time / 60) % 60, 10);
      var secs = parseInt(time, 10) % 60;
      var hourss = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(hours, 10) + ':';
      var minss = (mins < 10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(mins, 10) + ':';
      var secss  = (secs < 10 ? '0' : '') +(secs % 60);
      var timestring = ( hourss !== '00:' ? hourss : '' ) + minss + secss;
      return timestring;
    }
    //
    if(template.video.paused){
      var ctx = template.canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, template.canvas.width, template.canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(template.video, 0, 40, template.canvas.width, template.canvas.height);
      ctx.font = "20px Calibri";
      ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
      ctx.fillText("caption", 5, 20);
      var time = format(template.video.currentTime);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillText(time, 395 - ctx.measureText(time).width, 20);
    }
  },
  "click canvas":function(event,template){
    var screenshots = template.screenshots.get();
    screenshots.push({
      source: template.canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    });
    template.screenshots.set(screenshots);
  }
});
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for this answer, this helped me lear a lot (the first 3 prints of code) however when setting up the event maps I got confused , any chance to complete the code to make it workable and I will learn it from there?   I see you defined the var v  in timeupdate and loadmetadata  also so I got confused in how to copy the additional codes (and also the time format part) to make it workable .....thanks for your help really appreciate it and will see how to give you points.

Comment: And takes for pointing me out to reactive-var, first time found out about it .

Comment: I reworked my answer to provide a full working example (tested it locally).

Comment: Thank you :) appreciate your time